# how to echo and compare 2 bit sql value in php

Tags: php, sql

I have saved one data column as bit(2) in my sql table. column name = state2
when i checked the sql table using cpanel I can see the numbers there. I store 0-3 values there so I selected 2 bit as column type.

my sql column updates correctly. but now I am trying to use that value in my if condition. but if condition does not work with that, then I tried to echo the value in each row under column state2.

It prints empty string. why is that ? is there any special method to use with bit(2) data types.

check screenshot for value in sql table
[image]

Now this is what I am doing

```
$state2 = $row['state2'];
        echo '<td>'.$state2.'</td>';
```

I m not attaching full code because it is very long. but I hope this part is enough. I have setup it correctly because it prints other all values correctly in my html page as table row.

look below image and you will see results
[image]

what is the reason for this. below image show the data type of state2 column.
[image]

please help

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason my self. it was my fault,
I have not added state2 in select statement in sql
I added it and it worked perfectly
https://prnt.sc/u0big4